# How to find all the files in pwd that contains a unique keyord like "I have an important work"? in unix/linux?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, ubuntu-12.04

find unique keyword or string
find . "I have an important work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `pwd` I assume you meant current working directory.

```
grep -l "I have an important work" *
```